# Saving object with mongoose findOne / save doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My model is:

```
GigSchema = new Schema({
  lastUpdate: {
    type: Date,
    "default": null
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    "default": null,
    "enum": [null, 'mvp', 'code-review', 'extension', 'existent-code-review', 'internal', 'design']
  },
  meta: {
    type: Object,
    "default": {
      chats: 0,
      phoneCalls: 0,
      responseTime: null
    }
  },
  engaged: {
    type: Date,
    "default": null
  }
});
```

And when I do:

```
Gig.findOne({
  _id: data.gig
}).populate(populate).exec(function(err, gig) {
  gig.meta.chats += 1;
  return gig.save(function(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

I'm trying to update the `meta` field, but it doesn't actually save, but also no error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer has to do with using `gig.markModified('meta')` since I'm modifying the properties of an object.

Answer (score 3):

`Populate` should be used to get the references to documents in other collections. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

If you just want to update field in a document you can do the following:

```
Gig.findOne({_id: data.gig},  function (err, gig) {
    gig.meta.chats += 1;
    gig.save(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
})
```

Or you can also use [Model.findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

```
Gig.findOneAndUpdate({_id: data.gig}, { $inc: { meta.chats : 1 }}, {new: true}, function(err, doc){
    if (err){
        console.log(err); 
    } 
})
```

Comment: @Shamoon I'm sure there is a way to make it work with `populate`, however it's best to utilize methods that mongoose already provides, as they are very optimal. The purpose of `populate` is to allow `joins` in MongoDB (like in sql).

Comment: @Shamoon I updated my answer. You can use also use `Model.findOneAndUpdate`.

Answer (score 2):

use this structure... you have a problem with error catching and use update method if you want to update somethig, not save.

```
Gig.findOne({
  _id: data.gig
}, function(err, gig){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }else if(gig){
      Gig.update({_id: data.gig},{
         meta.chats : gig.meta.chats + 1;
     },
    {
      runValidators: true
    },
    function(err){
       if(err) throw err;
    }
    );
```

});

hope this helps you. i am wait a result, think its be ok.